# 503 Service Unavailable Google App Engine getting Null Pointer Exception

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I navigate to `localhost:8888/_ah/api/explorer` and invoking some endpoint's methods. `listEntities()` and `findEntity()` operate as usual but when I try to `addEntity()` to the datastore I get

`Aug 31, 2014 9:22:03 PM com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.find(JPAEntityManager.java:318)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.find(JPAEntityManager.java:256)`

I cannot create a new entity, but I can see the previous ones.
I checked my persistance.xml, but I don't see anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: I think you have a problem with injection of jpa entity manager dependancy. You need to configure jpa entity manager with stateless requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to somehow fix the problem, according to the `Entity` specification, among other things a class that has the `@Entity` annotation must have a no-arguments default constructor defined which I did not have. I do not know if this was the issue but the problem was fixed.